# Redux dispatch not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dispatcher

My call to the dispatcher isn't working. What I want to do is to fire a dispatcher in componentWillMount to update something in the initial state.

I have my reducer set up as follows:

```
// initial state
const pagesInitialState = {
    begin: false,
    basicInfo: false,
    location: false,
    education: false,
    summary: false
}

const CHANGE_PAGE_STATUS = 'CHANGE_PAGE_STATUS';

// action creator
const changePageStatus = (page) => ({
    type: CHANGE_PAGE_STATUS,
    page
})

// dispatcher
export const dispatchShowPages = (page) =>
    dispatch => {
        console.log('not here');
        dispatch(changePageStatus(page))
}

// reducer
export default function (state = pagesInitialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_PAGE_STATUS:
            let pages = Object.assign({}, state);
            let pageToChange = action.page;
            if (pages.pageToChange === true) {
                pages.pageToChange = false
            } else {
                pages.pageToChange = true
            }
            return pages
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I have my routes set up as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history'
import Main from './components/containers/Main'

import { dispatchShowPages } from './reducers/loadPages'

class Routes extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    dispatchShowPages('begin')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Main />    
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

In a different file I have

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Routes />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

I am hoping the dispatcher would change 'begin' in the initial state from false to true. But it doesn't seem to be to hitting that dispatcher. It gets to dispatchShowPages but not in the dispatch. My console.log('here') in the dispatcher isn't logging. What am I wiring wrong?

Comment: where in this code are you using Redux?  All there is here is a component and a bunch of functions.

Comment: did you forgot to `connect` `Routes`?

Comment: @Sagivb.g I have it in a different file

Comment: @DanO I have a store in a different file that takes the reducer

Comment: @Sagivb.g I defined dispatchShowPages in my reducer in the code above,

Comment: but you need to use the `dispatch` in order to really pass it to your `action-creator`. something like `dispatch(dispatchShowPages('begin'))`

Comment: I thought dispatch is used when I call dispatchShowPages? Since it is itself calling dispatch here ------ export const dispatchShowPages = (page) =>
    dispatch => {
        console.log('not here');
        dispatch(changePageStatus(page))
}. ------ Unless I'm understanding everything wrong

Comment: Which code is actually using that dispatch though? Hint: none. If you assign the return value of `dispatchShowPages('begin')` to a variable, that variable would be the inner function. Redux isn't actually being used anywhere. Btw your code looks like it's using redux-thunk middleware, are you?

Comment: Your dispatcher method will require the Redux-thunk middleware to be installed. Is this added in your store setup? Can you share your store setup file?

Answer (score 0):

Your `dispatchShowPages` function is never called because your function is "curried"

```
function mapDispatch (dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatchShowPages (page) {
       dispatch(changePageStatus(page))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(App)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `dispatchShowPages` in your reducer since you already have the action creator there. All you need to do is to use the Redux's `connect` function like so:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { changePageStatus } from './reducers/loadPages'

class Routes extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    this.props('begin')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Main />    
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  showPage: page => dispatch(changePageStatus(page))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Routes);
```

And don't forget to export `changePageStatus` out from your `loadPages`
 file.

Comment: @Krasmir, yeah I actually removed the dispatcher in the reducer and did my dispatch in the other file and it worked out. Thanks anyway!